# CSS/JS Display loader when page is loading

Tags: javascript, css

How can i show a loader when page is loading

I think JS function is

```
onload="myFunction()"
```

Working css loader : http://jsfiddle.net/33zch/60/

Comment: Wow, I see you've really tried hard ;) If you add the loader image onload it will only show once the page **has** loaded (and thus triggered the onload event). Instead you should have the loader displayed by default and *remove* it once the DOM has loaded. There's an example at http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".hoja").fadeOut("slow");
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `onload` function in javascript on `body`, which will do the logic of hiding the loader

```
//html
<body onload='hideLoader()'>
   <div id='loader' class="hoja">Loading...</div>
</body>

//js
window.hideLoader = function(){
   var loader = document.getElementById('loader');
   loader.style.display='none';
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/33zch/61/

Fiddle using setTimeout to show the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/33zch/63/ (thanks to Moob)

Comment: Page loads to quickly to even see the loader. Maybe put the hideloader part  of your example in a `setTimeout` so we can see the effect? http://jsfiddle.net/33zch/63/

Comment: yeah I thought of doing, but what if OP pasted the code directly to her production code. Hence didn't do that. Will add your link with an explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementsByClassName('hoja')[0].style.opacity = '0';
}
```

**OR**

```
window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementsByClassName('hoja')[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Working **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m_tanzi/33zch/64/)**